# Visudo NOPASSWD has no effect

Tags: macos, unix, sudo

So I got sick of entering my password using CLI. That's why I edited the Sudoers file.
But somehow it has no effect and I am still prompted to use sudo and enter my password. Yes, I am part of the admin group on this Computer.

Here is my while Sudoers file, just to be sure..

```
# sudoers file.
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
# Failure to use 'visudo' may result in syntax or file permission errors
# that prevent sudo from running.
#
# See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# Defaults specification
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
Defaults        env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
Defaults        env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
Defaults        env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
Defaults        env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
Defaults        env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
Defaults        env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
Defaults        env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
Defaults        env_keep += "TZ"
Defaults        env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
Defaults        env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
Defaults        env_keep += "HOME MAIL"

# Runas alias specification

# User privilege specification
root            ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin          ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Uncomment to allow people in group wheel to run all commands
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Same thing without a password
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Samples
# %users  ALL=/sbin/mount /cdrom,/sbin/umount /cdrom
# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your own user under the %admin line. It should look like this (replace Robbsen with your mac username):

```
# User privilege specification
root            ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin          ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
Robbsen         ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

More info [here](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/06/add-user-sudoers-file-mac/).

Comment: It's not working. The way I understand is that the '%admin' line changes privilege for all users in the admin group. Since I am in the admin group it should work like I did it in the first post, shouldn't it?